# SAML Subject name format

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, pingfederate

In the page attribute contract we are having a field called subject name format, but here there are so many formats as follow,

```
•   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
•   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailaddress
•   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509subjectname
•   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:Windows Domain Qualified name
•   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:kerberos
•   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:entity
```

could you guys please explain me why and where these name formats are being used.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a PingFederate thing - it's really all of SAML. The definitions are in [SAML-Core](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf#page=78) in Section 8.3. Most commonly, people use "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" as it allows for "free-form" adherence. You and your partner agree on a format, and just do it. The others add validation rules to the formatting of the SAML Subject.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on the response provided by Andrew, most Service Provider (SP) websites hosted on the internet rarely ever require a specific value for the subject name format.  Out of the many integrations with PingFederate and hosted SaaS applications configured, I haven't encountered a case where the format was required to be anything other than "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified".